# looking for web hosting or web dedicated servers services, not sure

Tags: web-hosting, looking-for-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I am building a website for a church, this websites uses mysql php and for list of members and savng events, etc... The problem is that i havee no much expirience publicating sites. i need web space to publish this site. and this web space have to be php and msql compatible. please help, any info will be much appreciated. looking to spend no more than 30.00 a month

thanks

Comment: You can do that for free, if you can get a subdomain from say [Free SUBDOMAIN](http://freedns.afraid.org/). That way you can make your own computer a server. But before doing this you need to ask your ISP about how much legal the whole thing is, since you be taking DNS names from a third party to host the site from your computer. Everything is free though, if all goes well.  Regards P.S. If you willing to make your computer a SERVER.

Answer (score 4):

Almost any host has this capabilities.  You are probably going to want to look for "shared hosting" offers by a company as you will not need a VPS or Dedicated Server.  Most shared hosting is $5-$30 a month and most allow at least one MySQL table.

Before you purchase, you may want to look up the company on http://www.webhostingtalk.com/ and read some reviews of the company.  You wouldn't want to start doing business with a company that has bad reviews and won't be able to offer any support.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, this information it is very usefull.

Answer (score 0):

Like Tim Withers said, Almost any host offers these for much of nothing a month. I would start with HostGator if I was you. Go with the knowledge that you get what you pay for.

Check out forums, and review sites for information about hosts, and see what is said, if there is bad after bad after bad, with very few good then chances are it is going to be bad. If it is good after good after good, with very few bad, well chances are it will be good.